# return возвращает undefined

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь делать задачи с codewars чтобы поднять скилл но вместо этого падает мая самооценка

```
"use strict";
    var n = 95;
    n = digital_root(n);
    function digital_root(n) {
        n = String(n);
        var sum = 0;
        var m = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            m = +n[i];
            sum += m;
        }
        if (sum > 10) {
            digital_root(sum);
        }
        else {
            return sum;
        }
    }
    alert(n);
```

Comment: Внутри условия должно стоять `return digital_root(sum);` )

Comment: появляется ошибка Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String (<anonymous>)

Comment: поставьте в начале функции debugger; и посмотрите что пошло не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам написали в комментариях: *Внутри условия должно стоять return digital_root(sum); )* – **OPTIMUS PRIME**.
Вот рабочий код:

```
"use strict";

var n = 95;

n = digital_root(n);

function digital_root(n) {
    n = String(n);

    var sum = 0;
    var m = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
        m = +n[i];
        sum += m;
    };

    if (sum > 10) {
      return  digital_root(sum);
    } else {
      return sum;
    };
};

alert(n);
```

Возвращает число - 5